# URL within Pathparam and Queryparam

Tags: javascript, java, rest, query-string, path-parameter

I get a `404 error` when trying to use this `POST` method:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload/new/{containerId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response create(@PathParam("containerId") String containerId,@QueryParam("documentType") DocumentType documentType, MultipartFormDataInput request) {
 ...
}
```

Is this `url-exemple` correct? : `.../rest/upload/new/110/?documentType=logo`

When not how should I whrite it with this QueryParams `?documentType`

Comment: try to use `.../rest/upload/new/110?documentType=logo`

Comment: @MeladEzzat i get the same `404-error`

Comment: ok, where the part  `.../rest/` come from

Comment: it come from `backend`

Comment: oh i get now an `505-error` from server `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "type" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (2f949274-ddbc-48f2-821d-2cd312bba52a, 0, \x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948445200000556000003000802000000405c..., error2.png, c267cfc3-5951-46bf-8d89-c8fc4514148b, null).
`